# Angular, Jasmine - Spying on a function, being executed inside $interval/$timeout services

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Good day!

I want to test whether parseUrl method is called, but as the result: test is failed - parseUrl was never called, although if I put the parseUrl() outside of the $interval service's function, then test pass successfully.

Here is the place, where parseUrl is called:

```
    testMethod() {
       let intervalPromise = this._$interval(() => {
         this.parseUrl('test', 'test_code_name');
       }, 500);
    }
    parseUrl(url, name) {}
```

Here is the test case:

```
it('Expect testMethod to be called', function () {
  TestService.testMethod()
  spyOn(TestService, 'parseUrl').and.callThrough();
  expect(TestService.parseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Also the fact is, if I put the testMethod() outside of the $interval service, then test pass successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you need to inject the `$interval` service (could use ngMock) and call `$interval.flush(500);`

```
var $interval;

angular.mock.inject(function (myModuleService, _$interval_) {
  // Initialize the service under test instance
  $interval = _$interval_;
});

it('Expect testMethod to be called', function () {
  TestService.testMethod()
  spyOn(TestService, 'parseUrl').and.callThrough();
  $interval.flush(500);
  expect(TestService.parseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval

> Use $interval.flush(millis) to move forward by millis milliseconds and trigger any functions scheduled to run in that time.